# Understanding linearly disjoint fields and how their rings of integers interact in a proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, tensor-products

Let $L,L'$ be linearly disjoint number fields (i.e. finite-degree extension of $\mathbb{Q}$). Their rings of integers are denoted $O_L,O_{L'}$. I am trying to understand a proof of how if $p$ is unramified in $L$ and $L'$, then it is unramified in the composite field $L\cdot L'$, but I am stuck in understanding some of the abstract-algebra steps. (I'll not write the proof, but focus directly on the abstract-algebra questions).

1) The first step involves using $O_L\cdot O_{L'} \subseteq O_{L\cdot L'} \subseteq \frac{1}{\gcd(d_L,d_{L'})} O_L\cdot O_{L'}$. I managed to find and understand the wiki article on what composite of field means, but what exactly does $O_L\cdot O_{L'}$ mean? Is it the smallest ring in $L\cdot L'$ that contains $O_L$ and $O_{L'}$?

2) The second step involves observing that $O_L\cdot O_{L'}$ is isomorphic to $O_L\otimes_\mathbb{Z} O_{L'}$. Why is this the case?

3) Some steps later, we used the observation that $(O_L\otimes_\mathbb{Z} O_{L'})/p\cdot (O_L\otimes_\mathbb{Z} O_{L'})$ is isomorphic to $(O_L/p\cdot O_L) \otimes (O_{L'}/p\cdot O_{L'})$ Why is this the case?

I'm fine with the rest of the proof.

Comment: Just so you know, the actual conclusion here (that $p$ is unramified in $LL'$ if it is in $L$ and in $L'$) does *not* require $L$ and $L'$ to be linearly disjoint; only your method of proof makes that a requirement.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322124/elementary-proof-that-mathfrakp-unramified-in-l-l-implies-unramified-in.

Comment: Yup, I am aware of that, thanks :) It's just that this proof is supposedly more accessible to things/an illustration of things I have learnt, so we were taught this special case

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Show the obvious bases for both rings correspond to each other (there's a natural map from the tensor product to $O_L \cdot O_{L'}$. (3) Write down a natural map in one direction or the other and prove it's a ring isomorphism (note the quotient rings here are finite, so check they have the same size as part of the work in order to simplify things).